# Blowfish Block Size 64bits - What to do when input is not a multiple of 64bits

Tags: encryption, blowfish, encryption-symmetric

I'm creating an application to encrypt a string of unknown length with Blowfish. The input can be of any length, and will therefore not necessarily be a multiple of 8 bytes.

What is the standard method for dealing with this situation? Perhaps fill in the end of the string with 0s? Presumably there's a more elegant way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a number of [padding mechanisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) (wikipedia) that you can choose from. The algorithms vary from simply appending zeros to the end to a padding mechanism that can be validated and/or removed.

Alternatively, you can use the [OFB mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Output_feedback_.28OFB.29) (wikipedia) to convert a block cipher into a stream cipher, and get rid of the requirement for padding.